# Get all library (non-Maven) projects from SVN in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, gradle, android-studio

I have a MainApp which refers to 2 other library projects. All projects are on different SVN servers.

The way I have been working on Eclipse ADT(not using Maven, which is not the good way) is that I imported all library projects one by one and then the MainApp - all within the same workspace. This way the library projects were easily referenced through project.properties ; because they used **relative path** of library projects. This also meant that I had to update all projects independently and no one-click project update was possible.

So I tried moving to Android Studio/Gradle build system. If I export the gradle files from my local workspace and then import project into AS, it finds all library projects and shows them up as modules in AS. The problem is that I cannot use SVN client in AS to work on my project - as AS assumes everything to be there on my local machine (and not as a SVN codebase)

The other approach I took was to import the build.gradle file for MainApp directly from SVN. This approach does not import the library projects, because, of course the MainApp does not know about the SVN URLs of the library projects.

How should I go around solving this problem, where I don't need to use another SVN client to play around my code ? And use **absolute URLs** for all library projects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs, there are several different solutions:

- Publish library projects to a local or remote Maven repository (e.g. via their Gradle builds), and declare artifact dependencies on them in MainApp's build. Publishing can be automated by having CI builds for the library projects.
- Include library projects' SVN repositories in MainApp's SVN repository using SVN externals, and have a single multi-project Gradle build.
- Use Prezi's [Pride](https://github.com/prezi/pride) tool to create a single multi-project build that spans multiple SVN repositories.

It's also possible to attach another Gradle project to an AS project (see the `+` icon in the Gradle tool window), but I'm not sure if/how this solves the problem at hand.